# android AlertDialog return date value

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

In Mike Dalasay's examples found here:
http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/07/android-alertdialog-example.html

He presents AlertDialog examples.  I am wanting to use the Time and Date Dialogs in these examples, making the functions return the value that was set by the Time and Date Pickers.

As a newbee to Java and Android,  I know how the change the return void to String, but I don't know how to pass the picker values to the return value.

Here is his original code:

Show AlertDialog with date picker.

```
public void alertDatePicker() {

    /*
     * Inflate the XML view. activity_main is in res/layout/date_picker.xml
     */
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_picker, null, false);

    // the time picker on the alert dialog, this is how to get the value
    final DatePicker myDatePicker = (DatePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.myDatePicker);

    // so that the calendar view won't appear
    myDatePicker.setCalendarViewShown(false);

    // the alert dialog
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setView(view)
            .setTitle("Set Date")
            .setPositiveButton("Go", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @TargetApi(11)
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    /*
                     * In the docs of the calendar class, January = 0, so we
                     * have to add 1 for getting correct month.
                     * http://goo.gl/9ywsj
                     */
                    int month = myDatePicker.getMonth() + 1;
                    int day = myDatePicker.getDayOfMonth();
                    int year = myDatePicker.getYear();

                    showToast(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);

                    dialog.cancel();

                }

            }).show();
}
```

Where the showToast is i would set String myDate and somehow get the return value out of the function:

```
public String alertDatePicker() {
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you going to show date and time values in EditText after returning these values? If yes then i have a code which will help you

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you have the variables `month` `day` and `year` declared in the `AlertDialog` class.  If you move then to the calling method, or class then the scope of them will be different.

eg

```
 int month = 0;
 int day = 0;

 new AlertDialog.Builder .....

 }).show ();

 System.out.println (month);
```